# Populating ember-data table from WebSocket

Tags: json, ember.js, websocket, ember-data

My backend is sending me this JSON (example):

```
{
  id: 0,
  list: [
         {username:'user_1', name:'Name1', surname:'Surname1', user:0},
         {username:'user_2', name:'Name2', surname:'Surname2', user:0},
        ]
}
```

I have the necessity to bootstrap my table `App.WUser` with that type of JSON. Data comes via WebSocket. My Ember.js schema is defined as follow:

```
App.WUser = DS.Model.extend({
  list: DS.hasMany('App.User')
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'), // primary key
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  surname: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.WUser')
});
```

I writed my custum Adapter for WebSocket implementation. Note that `App.WebSocketConnection` is a Mixin contains the connection handler (see the last snippet).

```
DS.SocketAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(App.WebSocketConnection, { 
  socket: undefined,

  init: function() {    
    socket = this.getSocket(); // activate WS connection (see Mixin)
    this._super();
  },

  find: function (store, type, id) {
     // empty block    
  },

  findAll: function (store, type) { 
    // empty block
  },

  createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    // code not relevant
  }
});



DS.SocketAdapter.map('App.User', {
    primaryKey: 'username'
});


DS.SocketAdapter.map('App.WUser', {
  list: {embedded: 'always'}
});
```

My Store

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.SocketAdapter.create({})
});
```

My Mixin:

```
App.WebSocketHandler = Ember.Object.extend({
  uri: 'ws://localhost:8080/App/atmosphere/chat/all',
  ws: ,

  init: function() { 
    this.ws = new WebSocket(this.uri));                                                                 

    // callbacks
    this.ws.onopen = function() {
      console.log('Connection established /all');
    };
    this.ws.onclone = function() {
      console.log('Connection closed /' + 'all');
    };
    this.ws.onmessage = function(data) {
      alert('New JSON message from server /all ' + data);    // <---- ???
    };

    this._super();
  },

  send: function(data) { 


    // not relevant method... this method simply send a message to the server
    /* 
   var some = ...

    this.ws.send( JSON.stringify( some ) );
    */
  }

});
```

Searching on Google, I reached to write this piece of code:

```
var JSONfromWebSocket = {
  id: 0,
  list: [
     {username:'user_1', name:'Name1', surname:'Surname1', user:0},
     {username:'user_2', name:'Name2', surname:'Surname2', user:0},
    ]
};
    var store = DS.get('defaultStore');
    store.loadMany(App.WUser, [0], JSONfromWebSocket); // should I specify the [0] id?

    (?) this.didCreateRecords(store, App.WUser, records(?), undefined); // is it a neccessary line?
```

Questions:

1. Where I put my piece of code?
2. Is my piece of code correct? Is it the correct way to boostrap data?
3. Is it correct the usage of custum primaryKey?
4. Considering my custum ID of table `App.User`; is it correct the call to loadMany() function?
5. Note that the JSON is coming from **onmessage** callback (see line `` `// <---- ??? `` ). How to call one  of functions - and which - (i.e.createRecords) inherited by the Adapter, passing it the JSON data?

I am a bit confused, but I hope i am in the right way... My problem is to glue the pieces of my code!

Thanks for patience!

Mattia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that you get only one `App.WUser` at a time.

So something like this

```
App.WebSocketHandler = Ember.Object.extend({
  uri: 'ws://localhost:8080/App/atmosphere/chat/all',
  ws: ,

  init: function() { 
    this.ws = new WebSocket(this.uri));                                                                 

    // callbacks
    this.ws.onopen = function() {
      console.log('Connection established /all');
    };
    this.ws.onclone = function() {
      console.log('Connection closed /' + 'all');
    };
    this.ws.onmessage = function(data) {
      DS.get('defaultStore').load(App.WUser, data);  //Simply load your json in the store.
    };

    this._super();
  },
```

Comment: Thaks so much! It works like a charm: [see link](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/9505/snapshot6t.png). An issue is that my foreign key appear to be null (and named as **user_id**, not as **user**). I think because I am serialize my record outside my Adapter. (Note that I do not use a custom Serializer. Should I?)

Comment: You want to specify that users are embedded into `App.WUser` at loading App.Adapter.map('App.WUser', {
  list: { embedded: 'load' }
}; See https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/embedded/embedded_loading_test.js#L92

Comment: and also you'll need to use `inverse` so ember data can find that `list` is where users are stored. See https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/inverse_relationships_test.js#L65

Comment: Sorry my insistence. I cannot see the light. Here is my User table http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tdWAPEaq . Is the definition of Models order relevant? Cannot find the proper way to set the **inverve** property. Thanks so much again!